# Getting error "Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8" while publishing code metrics on SonarQube from VSTS Build machine

Tags: sonarqube, azure-pipelines

Getting error "Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8"  while publishing code metrics on SonarQube from VSTS Build machine through build definition.

find below sonar-project.properties file,

```
sonar.projectBaseDir=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/app
sonar.verbose=true
sonar.analysis.mode=publish
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.sources=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/app
sonar.language=ts
sonar.ts.tslint.projectPath=tsconfig.json
sonar.ts.tslint.path=node_modules/tslint/bin/tslint
sonar.ts.tslint.typeCheck=true
sonar.exclusions=node_modules/**
sonar.ts.coverage.lcovReportPath=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/app/coverage/lcov.info
```

Error is:

[image: First Error Image]

[image: Second Error image]

Don't know what is wrong here?

Comment: What if you remove the line `sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8` in the sonar-project.properties file and re-build?

Comment: Yes, i have tried this already, but still showing same error.

Comment: And what if you execute `SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end` manaully in the agent machine?

Answer (score 0):

You can unset the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS variable and it will work example:

```
unset JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS && /sonar-scanner/bin/sonar-scanner XXX
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while generating APK in **Android Studio** IDE on Windows. Turns out `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` *Windows environment variable* was set by Eclipse IDE independently for something. I no longer needed Eclipse any way, so I deleted it like:

Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings > Advanced > Environment Variables > delete `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` in both User and System > Reboot.